# C++ How to catch Mouse wheel up and down?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, directx, mouseevent, directx-9

Is there any **ascii** value for mouse **wheel up and down**.
I found this for mouse wheel, but this one does not care if I'm scrolling down or up 8) and acting in boot states.

```
case 0x020A:    //MOUSE Whell
{
    g_fDistance += 0.5f;

}break;
```

Thanks for any help and suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No ascii for this, ascii is for characters, not hardware inputs.

I always use a device inputs library like OIS to do this : http://sourceforge.net/projects/wgois/
It does all the translation work for you to get clear transformed input informations about keyboards, joysticks, mouses, wiimote...

That way I avoid OS-specific libs and make my life easier.

Comment: Thank you for help that'll make my life easier too 8)

Answer (score 2):

There are two Windows messages, MWHEELUP and MWHEELDOWN. You can check MSDN for the exact details.